# Mac OS on Apple M1, disable prefetchers using MSR/MRS instructions

Tags: macos, assembly, cpu-architecture, apple-m1, arm64

I wrote a C program to toggle the bits corresponding to prefetchers in Mac OS on Apple M1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


#define ARM64_REG_HID5          s3_0_c15_c5_0
#define ARM64_REG_HID5_DisHwpLd ((int64_t)1<<44)
#define ARM64_REG_HID5_DisHwpSt ((int64_t)1<<45)

#define STR1(x) #x
#define STR(x)  STR1(x)

int main() 
{
    int64_t x;

    asm("mrs %0 ," STR(ARM64_REG_HID5):"=r"(x));
    printf("Before %llx\n", x);

    x^=ARM64_REG_HID5_DisHwpLd|ARM64_REG_HID5_DisHwpSt;
    asm("msr "STR(ARM64_REG_HID5)", %0": :"r"(x));

    asm("mrs %0 ," STR(ARM64_REG_HID5):"=r"(x));
    printf("After %llx\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiled without any issue, but when I ran the code, I got the following error.

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  sudo ./a.out
```

Can someone help me fix the issue?

Comment: Do MRS / MSR require kernel mode?  I'd expect that at least `msr` does.  The root user is still user-space, not privileged in the CPU sense.  A bug in a process running as root can't accidentally reset your whole machine (unless you get really unlucky and it makes some system calls.)

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to be in EL1 or higher to run these. You can't just reconfigure hardware from usermode.

Comment: I see, then is there a way to make a program run with Supervisor privilege?

Comment: You'll have to write a kernel extension for that.